# How do I create a method to get the size of a sub-tree or even the tree of a Binary search tree in java

Tags: java, methods, size, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

`

```
    private int size(Node node) 
    {
        Node n = node;
        if(n == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {   int leftside = size(n.left);
            int rightside = size(n.right);
            return leftside + 1 + rightside;
        }
    }
    public int size() 
    {
        int sizeOfTree = size(root);
        System.out.println("Size of the binary tree is: " + sizeOfTree);
        return sizeOfTree;
       
    }
```

## this provides the size of the entire tree, im not sure how it could be implemented to take a specific node and get size of its subtree

im just very confused, i would like a break down on how this can work

Comment: The method `private int size(Node node)` *does* return the size of subtree of the specified `node`. It uses recursion to get the sizes of the left subtree and the right subtree. Adding those together with 1 more for the current `node` gives the size of the current subtree.

Comment: If you created the tree, maintain a size field that is updated when you add or remove elements. Otherwise web search how to traverse a binary tree and count the items until you are done.

Comment: By the way, Why are you **shouting** at us? It won't help, and may discourage some from offering help.

Comment: Have you tried running the code in a debugger? Run the code one-step-at-a-time while monitoring variables.  Debugging a working program can help you  understand it better. There are more suggestions in [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) . You might also web search for "understanding recursion" or "recursion tutorial"